# How can I specify a search field for Elastic Search - FATAL -- : [...] ArgumentError (Must specify fields to search):

Tags: searchkick, ruby-on-rails-5.2

My rails 5 app is deployed to Heroku, but the search function results in a 500 status and tells me that I need to specify a search field for Elastic Search. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

repo:  https://github.com/GBressler/moldy-eggplants

Heroku log:
2018-12-03T20:58:37.320538+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-12-03T20:58:37.320469 #4]  INFO -- : [cb92c5ee-9b97-4939-944e-14a06610a61b]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"deadpool"}
2018-12-03T20:58:37.388702+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-12-03T20:58:37.388584 #4]  INFO -- : [cb92c5ee-9b97-4939-944e-14a06610a61b] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 68ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2018-12-03T20:58:37.399605+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-12-03T20:58:37.399462 #4] FATAL -- : [cb92c5ee-9b97-4939-944e-14a06610a61b]
2018-12-03T20:58:37.399680+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-12-03T20:58:37.399609 #4] FATAL -- : [cb92c5ee-9b97-4939-944e-14a06610a61b] ArgumentError (Must specify fields to search):
2018-12-03T20:58:37.399746+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-12-03T20:58:37.399683 #4] FATAL -- : [cb92c5ee-9b97-4939-944e-14a06610a61b]
2018-12-03T20:58:37.399827+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-12-03T20:58:37.399766 #4] FATAL -- : [cb92c5ee-9b97-4939-944e-14a06610a61b] app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:8:in `search'
2018-12-03T20:58:37.398344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path= "/movies/search?utf8= %E2%9C%93&search=deadpool" host=nameless-ravine-32235.herokuapp.com request_id=cb92c5ee-9b97-4939-944e-14a06610a61b fwd="179.6.192.118" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=86ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your search parameter attribute is not whitelisted in your Movies controller.

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :description, :movie_length, :director, :image, :rating)
end
```

In theory you can do something like ...

```
 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :description, :movie_length, :director, :image, :rating, :search)
end
```

Now when sending the params , just make sure it's wrapped in a movie object `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "movie" => {"search"=>"deadpool"}}`

Now just reference it accordingly in line 8 of your controller, so instead of `params[:search]`, you'll now use `movie_params[:search]`.  Did not test it, let me know if it works out.